# How to put MacBook Pro to sleep when the lid is closed and you remove the power?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, power, macbook-pro

I think I have a common use case that is not properly handle by Lion.

If I close the lid and remove the power supply, my macbook is not going to sleep mode and stays awake draining the battery. It's like having the Caffeine active.

In fact, I do have Caffeine started but it is inactive.

This happens quite regularly, do you know a solution for this?

Comment: Do you have any peripherals attached?

Comment: Not sure but I may had a phone charging over USB (iPhone or Android). Still I'm sure this should not be the cause because I discovered that the computer was still on after staying more than one hour in the backpack without any peripheral attached.

Comment: Does your screen stay bright because it might be your laptop's closing sensor (whatever it's called) broken.

Comment: Is has to be something else, the screen is dimmed and asks for the password after I open the lid.

Comment: I have the same problem - worked flawlessly with Snow Leopard!